# JavaScript validation suddenly stopped working despite correct IDs

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript Validation stopped working

I didnt change anything and I checked for the ID's as well. Al of them were correct. I dont understand what is wrong. It was working fine before, but now it stopped working when I press the submit button.
[image: This is the image of form and js]
[JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZICS.png)

```js
function validate() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
  var female = document.getElementById("female").checked;
  var errMsg = "";
  var result = true;
  var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
  if (name == "") {
    errMsg += "Name cannot be empty.\n";
  }
  alert(errMsg);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="register" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div id="alert"></div>
  <label for="name">Username : </label> <input class="reggie" type="text" name="nam" id="name"><br>
  <label for="password">Password : </label> <input class="reggie" type="text" name="passwd" id="password"><br>
  <label>Gender : </label> <label for="male">Male</label> <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male">
  <label for="female">Female</label> <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female"><br>
  <label for="email">Email : </label> <input class="reggie" type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
  <label>Please select your favourite Ice Cream flavours : </label><br>
  <label for="icecream1">Vanilla</label> <input type="checkbox" id="icecream1">
  <label for="icecream2">Chocolate</label> <input type="checkbox" id="icecream2">
  <label for="icecream3">Butterscotch</label> <input type="checkbox" id="icecream3"><br> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Should I post it as text? Cuz I really need help

Comment: Yes, you can also create a working snippet from the editor (But it's important not to include screenshots of code, errors, etc...)

Comment: function validate() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
    var female = document.getElementById("female").checked;

    var errMsg = "";
    var result = true;
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;

    if (name == "") {
        errMsg += "Name cannot be empty.\n";
    }
alert(errMsg); 
}

Comment: Basically I have some text boz which has name, password, email and gender buttons. And when you click submit, it shows an alert message to fill the fields. But somehow its not working even though the ID are correct

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Remove the `novalidate`  attribute from `<form method="post" id="register" novalidate="novalidate">`

Answer (score 0):

Returning in the submit event does not cancel the submit. You need to call preventDefault on the event object that gets passed into your function from the event.

To fix it easily, you can just replace your

```
regForm.onsubmit = validate;
```

to

```
regForm.onsubmit = (event) => { // event is a SubmitEvent
  if (!validate()) { // Runs the function and will cancel if it returns false
    event.preventDefault(); // This cancels the form submit.
  }
};
```